# AVI Generated From D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE->pData is Blank

Tags: c++, winapi, avi

I have a simple C++ application on Windows that is using DirectX to capture the screen to a bitmap vector, stored in format like this, based on WinDesktopDup sample [here](https://github.com/bmharper/WindowsDesktopDuplicationSample/) :

```
struct Bitmap {
    int                  Width = 0;
    int                  Height = 0;
    std::vector<uint8_t> Buf;
};
```

I am trying to write a collection of this captures to a video file. I am trying to write to an AVI file using Windows APIs

The Visual Studio 2019 project is [here](https://github.com/chentiangemalc/DumpScreenToVideo)

An AVI file is being generated, but it's blank and while seems to be valid, playing in Windows 11's media player, and VLC, and doesn't have any content just black screens.

The screen capture is being performed on has a resolution of 3840 x 2160. Each frame is taking about 33 MB of RAM, which is not very efficient but at this stage my goal is to get something that works. I am running as x64 and have plenty of free memory.

After the AVI header in file, the file is just full of 0 byte values:

[image]

[image]
The main section of code here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WinDesktopDup.h"
#include "WriteAVI.h"

int main()
{
    WinDesktopDup desktopDup;
    desktopDup.Initialize();
    desktopDup.CaptureNext();
    
    const int numberOfBitmaps = 60;
    const int frameRatePerSecond = 2;
    Bitmap bmp[numberOfBitmaps];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBitmaps; i++)
    {
        bmp[i].Width = desktopDup.Latest.Width;
        bmp[i].Height = desktopDup.Latest.Height;
        bmp[i].Buf.resize(desktopDup.Latest.Buf.size());
    }

    int counter = 0;
    bool done = false;

    while (!done)
    {
        printf("Capturing frame %i / %i\r\n", counter, numberOfBitmaps);
        desktopDup.CaptureNext();
        std::copy(desktopDup.Latest.Buf.begin(), desktopDup.Latest.Buf.end(), bmp[counter].Buf.begin());

        counter++;
        if (counter >= numberOfBitmaps)
        {
            counter = 0;
            done = true;
        }
        //if <some event triggered> done = true;
        Sleep(1000 / frameRatePerSecond);
    }

    printf("Writing to AVI ...\r\n");

    // dump bitmaps to video
    wchar_t fileName[] = L"C:\\support\\test.avi";
    CAVIFile aviFile(fileName, desktopDup.Latest.Width, desktopDup.Latest.Height);
    
    BITMAPINFO  inf;
    memset(&inf, 0, sizeof(inf));
    inf.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(inf.bmiHeader);
    inf.bmiHeader.biWidth = desktopDup.Latest.Width;
    inf.bmiHeader.biHeight = -desktopDup.Latest.Height;
    inf.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    inf.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    inf.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    void* bits = nullptr;
    HDC     srcDC = GetWindowDC(NULL);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBitmaps; i++)
    {
        HBITMAP dib = CreateDIBSection(srcDC, &inf, 0, &bits, nullptr, 0);
        memcpy(bits, bmp[i].Buf.data(), bmp[i].Width * bmp[i].Height * 4);


        for (int j = 0; j < (15 / frameRatePerSecond); j++)
        {
            aviFile.AddFrame(dib);
        }
        DeleteObject(dib);
    }

    DeleteObject(srcDC);
}
```

Comment: not related to main problem but why so inefficient code ? first what visible - `CreateDIBSection` - at first why in loop instead once before loop ? than for what need `CreateDIBSection` at all ? for pass `HBITMAP dib` to `AddFrame(dib);`. but what `AddFrame` doing ? it get bits from `HBITMAP` inside `MakeDib`. so really it need bitmap bits (for `AVIStreamWrite`) instead . you have this bits from begin - but instead use it direct - you allocate hbitmap and memory for it (in loop !) copy bits to this memory. then allocate another memory in `MakeDib`. copy bits to this memory.. all this need fix

Comment: There are lots of issues : 1) the sample you link pretends "Microsoft's sample it's more complex than necessary" but it just doesn't work properly, uses too much GPU/CPU, creates flickering screen etc. I suggest you restart and use Microsoft's one. 2) timeout 0 is bad for AcquireNextFrame. 3) DXGI Output Duplication is *not* a capture/screenshot API, it reads what frames are available. 4) you shouldn't use GDI but use proper Windows streaming API like Media Foundation. 5) performance is pretty bad since you copy to GDI line by line, etc.